# When will drcsim-nightly switch to 2.4 release?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I presume that 2.4 is the latest official release.  Why is the nightly build still installing 2.3?

I thought nightly was supposed to be the most up to date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2453/when-will-drcsim-nightly-switch-to-2.4-release?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-04-18**:
Same for downloading source from bitbucket and compiling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It can happen that some time elapses between development on a release branch and those changes being merged back to the `default` branch, which is where the -nightly releases are created.  The `default` branch is also the branch that you'll use when building from source unless you explicitly switch branches.

We [just merged](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/225) from the `drcsim_2.5` branch back to `default`.  So the next -nightly release will contain 2.5.x.

We merge fixes from the release branches back to `default` periodically.  If you notice that something's missing from `default`, please let us know.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0